# UITextView doesn't scroll sometimes

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextview, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

While typing in a `UITextView` sometimes it scrolls down to *current line*(**case a**) but it doesn't the other times(**case b**).

There's another problem which is:

The same `UITextView` sometimes show all the text in it (**case 1**) but other times it doesn't show the last line of text(**case 2**).

Whenever **case 1** happens **case a** follows.
and Whenever **case 2** happens **case b** follows.

This is the hierarchy of the view:
[image]

Size(*variable height-fixed width*) of these `UITextView`s as well as `UICollectionViewCell`s are calculated using `sizeWithFont:constrainedToSize:lineBreakMode:`

Limits of height are set from 43 to 120.

if height>43 then enableScrolling is set to `YES`, otherwise to `NO`(**Logic X**).

Scrolling is enabled when `textViewBeginEditing` and **Logic X** is applied when `textViewEnded` Editing.

There is no scrolling in **case 2**.

Please suggest cause and workarounds.

Answer (score 0):

On iOS7, I think that you could leave the `UITextView's` `scrollEnabled` property set to `YES` in all cases. If it contains less text it will just not scroll. If you set the property while configuring the cell, you might get this kind of weird behavior, because `UIKit` is reusing those cells and probably the `UITextView` too.

For making the last line visible, I'm guessing you need to calculate the text view size more accurately. Try using the `attributedText` to set the text, with all the formatting you need. Then, in order to calculate the size, you can do it like this:

```
NSAttributedString *text = self.yourCellsTextView.attributedText;
UITextView *calculationView = [[UITextView alloc] init];
[calculationView setAttributedText:text];
CGSize size = [calculationView sizeThatFits:CGSizeMake(self.yourCellsTextView.frame.size.width, FLT_MAX)];
CGFloat finalMessageHeight = size.height;
```

Hope this helps :).